# Building Predicate Producing Syntax Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate

I am building a complicated NSPredicate that varies depending on many variables.  The method that seems to work best is to build each clause separately as a string, combine the strings into an array, covert the array back into a string and read it into the predicate using predicateWithFormat.  It works great except in the one case where I am comparing dates and I get the following error:

> Unable to parse the format string "(canceled != 1)&&(starttime >=2016-12-18 13:50:41 +0000)"'

Here is the line where I build this clause.

```
typePredClause = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(starttime >=%@)",nowstr];
```

`starttime` is an `NSDate` in the entity and this is how I get `nowstr`

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
             NSString *nowstr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

I know that it would be ideal to just use `predicateWithFormat` and leave the strings out of it but the predicate is so complicated that building it is the only to go.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

As reference, here is code where I combine all the clauses.

```
if (typePredClause.length > 0)
[predArr addObject:typePredClause];
NSString *predStr = [predArr componentsJoinedByString:@"&&"];
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predStr];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `starttime` is some `NSDate` property, you should not create a string from the date. Just use the `NSDate`.

And your approach to creating your predicate is all wrong. Do not build it using a bunch of strings. Do it like this:

```
NSPrediate *canceledClause = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"canceled != %d", someInt];
NSPredicate *startTimeClause = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(starttime >= %@)", [NSDate date]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[ canceledClause, startTimeClause ]];
```

Comment: I redid it without strings using the compound predicate approach and problem solved.  Thanks!